# Bootstrap 4 Cards IE 11

Tags: sharepoint, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

On SharePoint in the DeltaPlaceHolderMain, I have a content editor webpart, this has HTML in it which has the cards in card-columns, in IE 11 when putting the cards to more than fits on the scren, it pushes out the screen scroll and does not adhear to the media statements, i have put in. its all good when i resize, it seems that text is pushing it past, as it does not wrap text in the card divs... in Chrome its fine, works a treat, its as iff some addtional CSS is needed to handle something in IE 11. In IE 11 the exact same html (rendered without SharePoint just as a HTML file) works fine. So again it must be some SP thing in IE 11

Comment: Can you please provide the detailed steps to produce the issue with sample code and the snapshot of the output which your are getting in IE? It can help us to understand the issue and we can try to produce the issue on our end. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS to your page:

```css
.ms-webpart-cell-vertical {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Web part containers use `display: table` and don't wrap correctly on IE11.